# Running subpart of tensorflow model on CPU

Tags: performance, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I got a model which consists of several submodels. A few of these submodels should be run on CPU (as it has to use a for loop and is not suited for GPU), all others on GPU.
I tried to call like this in the call method of my model:

```
        call(self,inputs):
        ... preprocess stuff ... 
        aout   = mymodel.SubModelA(preprocessed_in)

        with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            bout = mymodel.SubModelB(aout)

        cout = mymodel.SubModelC(bout)

        with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            dout = mymodel.SubModelD(cout)
```

however, this is extremly slow. Is there no way to do this quickly? The submodels B and D way faster if I train them separately, but for prediction and training I need the model to function as one.

Assuming there is no simple solution to this, the only way to speed things up would be I guess to have separate models M1, ..., Mn, process my entire dataset iteratively by M1 to Mn, changing in between GPU and CPU according to needs.
If I did this, how would I train the entire sequence? How would I perform the gradient step here?